# How to generate authorization request header?

Tags: python, flask, postman, http-headers

How can I generate a authorization request header ?

I have read about [authorization request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) and I generated one using username and password in base 64, but when I pass it on request header it doesn't work (`"error": "invalid_client`).

Using Postman to make the request everything works :

```
POST /oauth/token
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
authorization: Basic M1g4Vlk2QllHOFFJTDA3amt1cWpsUnNKOmhoWkNlSEg0SzFuVVJ2VTZmNUs5MmFiTlNSN3h3ZlBCYVN6OXI1WG1pcDNZOGJCbA==
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.5
accept: */*
host: 127.0.0.1:5000
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 97
```

**Obs** ¹ : The api uses the password grant type and return a bearer token

**Obs** ² : When I generate a authorization request header using username and password (`base64.b64encode(b'')`) the lenght of the output is 20 characters

Comment: `b'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(b'username:pass')` ?

Comment: Doesn't work, this is how I'm doin by now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flask Authlib, you can define three types of  Auth methods : client_secret_basic, client_secret_post and none, these types indicates witch parameters and how you need to pass them in headers. This is referente to [RFC6749](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/specs/rfc6749.html#token-endpoint-auth-methods) spec.

Answer (score 1):

How do you send this post request in python?

Why not use `requests`? You don't even need to care about it:

```
import requests

requests.post(url, data=data, auth=(username, passwd))
```

Comment: `requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token', data=payload, header=header).json()`, because besides username and password, I need to pass client_id, client_secret, scope and grant_type. Yes, I did try `auth` but I receive the same error.

Comment: Use `response.request` to see the sent request and compare with the worked one in postman. Maybe you can list `res.request.header` `res.request.body` or something useful in your question to help us and yourself.

Comment: Doesn't [work](https://ghostbin.com/paste/t3csc) (using `b64encode(b'username:password')` on application) and [work](https://ghostbin.com/paste/3jqep) (using the Postman's `'authorization': 'Basic ...'`)

Comment: I don't know why, but passing the client_id and client_secret in base 64 it works, I know the Http protocol specifies to pass the username and password ... I researched to  undertand it, but I couldn't find nothing. Thanks for the support, I apreciate it !